# My phone is in an update boot loop

Tags: hardware, boot-loop

I have an update for my Samsung Galaxy Exhibit.
I clicked on *Update* and it started updating my phone, but now it goes to the update screen, loads about 25% and then restarts my phone. It has been happening for a half hour now, what should I do?

Taking the battery out did not help, either.

Comment: Do you still have warranty?

Answer (score 0):

Two options depending on the status of your phone.

1. If you are rooted and have a custom recovery (and backup), simply reboot into recovery and restore a backup of your original rom.
2. If you are not rooted, then you will need to download the original firmware file (try SAMMOBILE.COM) and then flash it using Odin - There are lots of tutorials on how to flash using Odin, so I won't go into detail. Once you have successfully done this, then re-download the updated firmware, as it sounds like your original download is corrupted.